# Scikit-Learn Regressor with constraints

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I'm trying to fit a linear model for some problem.
It's simple objective to find linear combination: ∑=0

the problem is that the resgressor learn the trivial solution: =0.
Is there any option to add a constraint to the regressor? such as ∑=1 ?